# Parsing XML data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have gone through the basics in xml and now trying to parse xml data using javascript.
I have taken help from w3schools & written the following code but parsing is not happening and a blank page is getting displayed. Please help...

The xml file am using is **books.xml**:

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

The **Html** code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("C:/Users/A/Desktop/books.xml");

document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unless you're doing this out of academic curiosity, you would do better to use a pre-written library like jQuery. Check here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: is your `xmlDoc` an XML object? do a `console.log(xmlLog);` to be sure.

Comment: @JonathanM Actually I have tried very hard but not getting it...is it not possible with js?

Comment: @Oriol Can you tell me the specific dom methods....

Comment: @Anuraag For example: `document.createElement`, `parent.appendChild(child)`, `element.innerHTML`

Comment: @Anuraag, see this example: http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code, it works (I'm using Mozilla Firefox 28 on Mac OSX).

Remember that on Windows systems the directory separator is a backslash \ and NOT a slash /
Try to change that in your xml path. Maybe you see a blank page because you didn't provide a fallback in case your ajax request cannot find that xml. If you're using Firebug you should see a "404 Not Found" error when trying to GET that xml.

Comment: I cant understand no matter what I try that code is not working in my pc. Tried with Firefox also :(

Comment: Changed the file destination as "file:///C:/Users/A/Desktop/books.xml"